# Share a folder in tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

How can I enable a folder to be accessable using a browser with tomcat 6 ?

I think I need to add a context to web.xml ?

I'm trying -  
So when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/myfiles I expect to see the contents of c:\temp

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `META-INF/context.xml`, and there in the `<Context>` element set `docBase` to point to the desired directory.

[See here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) the attributes to set in the `Context` element

Comment: Could you post a complete context.xml ? I tried that but its not displaying. Do I need to place the folder to be shared in the webapps folder ?

Comment: @user470184 check the link I added

Comment: @user470184 and you probably need to enable directory listing too in conf/web.xml