# Saving files across server restarts using Tomcat in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration

I have been trying to find answers to this question, and I'm currently baffled.

We are using Eclipse for development and testing, and the Tomcat 7 server is started from within Eclipse.  As there are frequent changes to the code, it automatically restarts and reloads the Spring beans when changes are made to the source code.  From what I see, it rebuilds the whole "WebContent" area for the webapp.

So, inside the app, I tried writing the output file images that are created into the tomcat location where it puts the wtbwebapps folder.   However, since this seems to be re-generated every time you restart the server, there is no persistence to these files, and since I store the location of the file in my database, I'd like the file to be there when I restart the server over and over.

From my research, it seems that you can set up a "docbase" in the context for Tomcat ( [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133568/share-a-folder-in-tomcat) ).  Then I saw this: [Eclipse thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=207615&S=58a4ea9aa25e8f34e2001acc24de28ad#msg_664875) and they say that the docbase attribute isn't supported in Eclipse.

So does anybody here have any idea where I can put these file where they'll still be available via the web?  These images are basically the results of simulations that are run, and it's kind of necessary to have them available.

Thanks so much for any thoughts.  I don't have code examples here because it seems to be totally a configuration thing.  If there is any info that I can provide that would help, I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend storing any app state in a location not directly accessible from the web and not as part of your app cod tree. Define a separate folder and then use an environment variable or similar to let your code find the app state folder. Then have your servlet handle request for images and fetch from app state folder.

Comment: But can you fetch an image from a folder that isn't in the web-accessible area?  I thought for protection, it has to be under that structure in order to be accessible via something like http://localhost:8080/Appname/result/myimage.bmp .  If that makes sense.  If I just put it somewhere else, how does tomcat know that's an allowable area?

Comment: Your servlet can respond with generated content or content it reads from somewhere on the file system or in database, etc. Say you get request for /Appname/result/myimage.bmp and you map /AppName/result to your servlet. You can take the rest of the URL and use it to lookup a local file, which your servlet then reads and forwards to the client. Tomcat isn't serving the file in this case; your servelt is doing it. This gives you a lot more flexibility. Today the files can be in some local directory, tomorrow in database, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I get it.  But to do this, do we have to read in the file and write it out?  We are using Spring MVC, so what gets fed back is served via jsp.   I think I understand what you are saying and I will talk to someone else I work with about trying that.   I see that this also provides an additional level of security to the access, as we don't have to manage any additional directory protection where the images are stored.

Comment: Yes, write a servlet to read from file system and write into the response object. Make sure to set the mime type correctly in response. You can have this servlet exist side-by-side your Spring MVC infrastructure. Just give it a separate url to own.

Comment: Ok, I will look into this.  One issue is we also have the url embedded in some jsp to show a clickable thumbnail, and that I don't know how to do this way, since the jsp is served by our spring-mvc controller.  Lots to think about, thanks.